Android Emulator with Internet Access on GitHub Actions or Azure CI without Self-Hosted Agent or Mocks?
I'm currently running UI tests on an Android emulator as part of my CI pipeline using GitHub Actions (hosted runners) on Linux. However, I'm running into issues where the emulator does not seem to have internet access (e.g., ping: unknown host google.com).
I've done some research and discovered that this limitation is likely due to how GitHub-hosted runners (especially those running on Microsoft Azure) are designed, with restrictions around network access in virtualized environments. From what I understand, nested virtualization is used for Android emulators, and GitHub-hosted runners (on Linux, Windows, and macOS) do not provide network access to these nested environments. Here are the main points I've gathered:

GitHub-hosted runners (whether Linux, Windows, or macOS) do not provide network access to emulators running in their virtual environments due to networking and virtualization restrictions.

This seems to be tied to how Azure VMs handle virtualized environments, where emulators don't have full access to the host's network interface.

The only currently suggested workarounds include:

Setting up a self-hosted runner, where you have full control of the network and can enable internet access for the emulator.
Using mock services instead of relying on real internet access during tests.



Before I go down the self-hosted route, has anyone successfully enabled internet access on Android emulators in CI environments using GitHub Actions or Azure without using a self-hosted agent or mocking the network?
Alternatively, is there a definitive explanation for why internet access is not available in this setup? Any insights or suggestions are much appreciated!
